# Retrieve property bag for sub sites using JSOM

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

I need to go through all sites belonging a site collection to validate a property bag of them. following is my code. the problem is the second call to get the property uses only one of the sites. I thought it maybe go through sites one by one and get the property bag, but it doesn't. it gets property bag of only one of sites, I think it is the last one.

```
RootContext = new SP.ClientContext(RootSiteUrl);
SubSites = RootContext.get_web().get_webs();                        
RootContext.load(SubSites);
RootContext.executeQueryAsync(

Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {
    var subSiteEnum = SubSites.getEnumerator();

    while (subSiteEnum.moveNext()) {

        var Site = subSiteEnum.get_current();

        var SiteContext = new SP.ClientContext(Site.get_url());
        var allProperties = SiteContext.get_web().get_allProperties();                                                                       
        SiteContext.load(allProperties);
        SiteContext.executeQueryAsync(

                Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {
                    var Prop = allProperties.get_fieldValues()["myProp"];
                    alert(Site.get_title());
                    if (Prop != undefined) {
                        alert(Prop);
                    }
                }),
                Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {
                    alert('Misslyckades med att hämta property bags för ' + Site.get_title() + ' error: ' + args.get_message());
                })
        );
    }
}),
Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {
    alert('Misslyckades med att hämta subsiter för s: ' + args.get_message());
})
);
```

Comment: I sovled it. For those to want to know, I used JQuery Deferred. I placed the second async query to a deferred method and call the method within the while loop.

Comment: Could you please post it as an answer and mark it as a solution. It should be great if you paste the working solution as well. Thank you.

Comment: Using deferred is a nice way to sequentially chain asynchronous callbacks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15504921/asynchronous-loop-of-jquery-deferreds-promises

Comment: @Medes If you solved the issue, please answer your own question as an answer and not as a comment. It'll help others (and you'll have a chance to get upvotes ^^)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sovled the problem using JQuery Deferred. I placed the second async query to a deferred method and call the method within the while loop.